# How find older datetime column for multiple entries in row?

Tags: r, datetime

There are multiple entries for the same ID in the table shown below. Out of that, I need only the one which is having an older date in TIME column and drop remaining one.

```
ID      TIME
1       1/20/2016
1       1/21/2016
1       1/19/2016
1       2/10/2016
2       1/18/2016
2       1/19/2016
2       1/17/2016
3       1/16/2016
3       1/17/2016
```

I need an output like mentioned below,

```
ID:1   1/19/2016
ID:2   1/17/2016
ID:3   1/16/2016
```

No need of exact format of output but result should match.

Any help that would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `df$date <- as.Date(df$TIME, '%m/%d/%Y'); aggregate(date ~ ID, df, min)`

Answer (score 2):

It can be achieved with the `dplyr` package, grouping by `ID` and filtering bottom `TIME` value.

For example:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 2, 2), TIME = c('2016-01-01', '2017-01-01', '2016-12-15', '2017-12-15'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df$TIME <- as.Date(df$TIME)


require(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(ID) %>% top_n(n=-1, wt = TIME)`
```

Comment: You could use `mutate` within the chain to parse the date, but this is a good answer.

Comment: What if it is in this format " 1/17/2016 12:00".
Will above code work??